# Display text within the boundary

Tags: jquery, css, tooltip

How to wrap up a paragraph? I want to use a tooltip to display something. But if you look at the first cell, some of the contents are out of the tooltip's boundary.

http://jsfiddle.net/zhshqzyc/4hN2M/21/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/6MCFR/1/

The problem is you are using `line-height` to center your text. If you get rid of that aspect and allow the tooltip's height to be organic, no matter how many lines of text there are the tooltip will expand to fit.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `line-height` to not `125px`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#tooltip { 
    position:absolute;
    background: #CCC630;
    color: #AACBA;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 14px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    margin-top:30px;

    }
```

Make this change. I basically removed height and width and let it adjust accordingly. Hope this helps